# How to keep appending instead of replacing

Tags: javascript

```js
const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1", 
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
    ]
const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");

function getProducts() {
    Sheet.forEach((product) => {
        productsEl.innerHTML += `<div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src=${product.UPC} alt="Image Unavailable" height="170px;" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemdesc">
                <h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price"><span id="price">${product.Price}</span></h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p id="desc">${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart(this);">
                <button id="addToCart" > Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    </div>`; 
    })
}

getProducts(); 

let numUnit = document.getElementById("#Unit")
let itemTitle = document.getElementById("item")
let itemPrice = document.getElementById("$Price")

function addToCart(button) {
    const parent = button.closest('.productContainer'),
    Title = parent.querySelector('#itemName')
    Price = parent.querySelector('#price')
    Code = parent.querySelector('#desc')

itemTitle.textContent = Title.innerText + ' ' + Code.innerText
    itemPrice.textContent = Price.innerText
        
    //numUnit.textContent = '1'
}
```

```html
    <div class="Sheet">
    </div>
     <div class="cartContainer">
        <div class="cart">
            <h3>Cart: <span id="allNum"> 0</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="itemUl">
            <ul>
                <li id="Units">Units:<span id="#Unit"></span></li>
                <li id="Items">Item:<span id="item"></span></li>
                <li id="Price">Price:<span id="$Price"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Currently, when I press addToCart the title and price go to my cart but then when I press it again it replaces it. How can I add it below instead of replacing it? I know there is a way to create elements but I was wondering if there is another way since my elements are already created.

Comment: Why would you add an item in a new row when you add the same item. It should update the unit column.  You have used a lot of query selectors in this code. You should try rewriting it.

Comment: so should I set itemUl as an array or what? sorry I am a beginner

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should change?

Comment: Do you populate the carts according to a from? I see that you hardcode the list just with one item.

Comment: I had it in an excel sheet and just switched it to a huge JSON file with thousand of objects.

Comment: So, you need to take the carts from the stylesheet and populate it in the website?

Comment: Add new fields to the source data {unitConsumed: number}. Update unitConsumed and InStock property in the source when item adds and remove. Iterate the source to print the cart list, and check if any item has unitConsumed greater than zero.